# Stop Maven downloading plugins from private repository?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, nexus, maven-repository

We have a company Nexus repository which has just a couple of private libraries but it mostly mirrors the public Maven Nexus repository.

The repository is on a private network which can only be accessed by VPN.

This is accessed using a `settings.xml` config like so (redacted)

**User Settings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">


    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>FOOSNAPSHOTS</id>
            <username>foo-publisher</username>
            <password>12345</password>
       </server>
        <server>
            <id>BARRELEASES</id>
            <username>bar-publisher</username>
            <password>12345</password>
       </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>foo-nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://foo/repository/foo-maven-group/</url>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>bar-nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://foo/repository/bar-maven-group/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>allow-snapshots</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots-repo</id>
                    <url>https://foo/repository/hosted-foo-snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>foo-snapshots-repo</id>
                    <url>https://foo/repository/hosted-bar-snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

In a sample spring boot project, when trying to build a project when not connected to the VPN it fails because it cannot get plugins like the following.

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/bobbytables/.m2/repository), foo-nexus (https://foo/repository/foo-maven-group/)] -> [Help 1]

This is annoying as it then requires to be on the VPN, is there a way to get Maven to download plugins from public repos?

**Parent POM**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>foo.shared-maven-parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared-maven-parent-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.202211110800.52-x6937aa5.master</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>foo.bar-service</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>bar-service</name>
  <description>Foo Bar - Bar is Foo</description>

  <modules>
    <module>contract</module>
    <module>server</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
    <mcu.version>${project.version}</mcu.version>
    <!-- Project's contract version -->
    <mcu.project.contract.version>1.202204111324.39-x6bb54a3.master</mcu.project.contract.version>
  </properties>

</project>
```

**Service POM**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>foo.bar-service</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar-service</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>foo.bar/groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Listing-command Server</name>
    <description>Listing-command Server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>foo.shared-maven-bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>shared-maven-bom-chassis</artifactId>
                <version>1.202211160925.72-xa9bdde9.master</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>foo.shared-commons.spring-boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.202211110857.90-xcb97a1c.master</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <!-- Starter for Stackdriver Trace -->
</project>
```

How can I specify either at project or user level that I want plugins to download from the public repository?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a repository manager than you should download everything from that repository manager ... otherwise you are circumvent the idea of such setup...

Comment: if you set `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` you redirect everything. BTW, having two such entries does not make sense.

Comment: So should I just have one server defined?